# Autosys R11 job dependency with dependent-job run-time condition

Tags: time, dependencies, scheduling, autosys

In Autosys R11, I need job_b to run only if job_a succeeded within the last X hours. Apparently, [R11 allows you to "set look back dependencies on job_a to only run if job_c has ran to S within X hours."](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1837263/1112765) What would be the syntax?

```
s(job_a)
```

What would I add if I want my job to run only if job_a succeeded within the last 12 hours, for example?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Should be

condition: success(job_a,12.00)

status(job_name, hhhh.mm)