# AutoSys Job multiple dependencies issue: s(1) & s(2) & s(3)

Tags: scheduled-tasks, scheduling, scheduler, job-scheduling, autosys

I got 4 jobs:
1, 2, 3, 4.

2's condition: s(1);
3's condition: s(2);
4's condition: s(1) & s(2) & s(3)

all these jobs are **daily jobs**

the first day is ok.
the second day, the 4th job triggered **mutilple times**:

I think when 1 success, and the status of 2 and 3 are still 'success'(the last days status), 
so the job 4 triggered,

then 2 success, triggered again...

so is there any solution for this? becase I only want these condition is based on the current day's result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is already answered on stackoverflow.com
The solution depends on the version of Autosys you are using. If it is R11, the newest version, you can set look back dependencies on job_a to only run if job_c has ran to S within X hours.

Full answer here:
[Autosys dependency on mainframe job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1780761/autosys-dependency-on-mainframe-job)

Comment: Thanks.  after go through the user manual, I got the feature you are talking about, it's called 'Look-Back Dependencies'. but at last, I choose to use 'Box'. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes if you are running latest version of Autosys you can set the success condition depending on time.
In your case you can set as:
4's condition: s(1, 23.00) & s(2, 23.00) & s(3, 23.00)

This condition checks if the jobs 1,2,3 were successful within last 23 hours.

Format is:
S(*jobname*, *hh*.*mm*)

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to include all the 4 jobs in a Box job, and whenever the Box jobs starts all the job will become active and will run only in the completion of all the dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Put all 4 jobs in a box. Then, you can change the run condition of job4 to just the success of job3.