# Autosys R11 Job Scheduling with delay

Tags: autosys

I have a BOX_A which have JOB_A and BOX_AB. Once BOX_A is started, i want to start BOX_AB, after 30 sec only when JOB_A is success.

```
BOX_A
     - JOB_A
     - BOX_AB
             - JOB_AB1
             - JOB_AB2
```

We can use the condition to find JOB_A's success but how to start after 30 sec's once JOB_A's success.

JOB's in BOX_AB depends on JOB_A bootup. So need a delay before the BOX_AB's jobs starts up.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure how exactly you can add 30 seconds delay but you can add delay in terms of minutes, something like this:
SUCCESS(job_A, 00.05)

Format is: SUCCESS(jobname, hh.mm) or S(jobname, hh.mm)
 You can also refer my answer in the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14150845/autosys-job-multiple-dependencies-issue-s1-s2-s3/32206126#32206126)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Coder Edited as per your suggestion

Comment: I tested, not work, S(jobname, hh.mm) means in the past hh.mm, there was a jobname run successfully. It was not the means of delay of hh.mm

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would be to create a process which simply slept and added that as a dependency